# Null value in the database to be displayed as nothing - Twig

Tags: php, twig

I have a field in the database which is with nullable=true, but when I set a null value to it and then display it in twig this way **{{ null_variable}}** it displays the text "empty_value". How can I display nothing instead of this text? The onlu thing I can think of is this way

```
{% if variable==NULL %}
<td></td>
```

but I don't think it's a good way of doing this.

Comment: How are you fetching the data from the database?

Comment: I fixed this problem, but now I get another one which is more weird. I have date fields which can be nullable and when I don't fill them they are displayed as 2012-08-09 - today's datea lthough in the database they are NULL. :( Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a weird behavior, Twig shouldn't returns 'empty_value'.

Are you sure you are not using it within a form?

Anyway, here is someway to do:

```
{% if variable is defined %} // $variable was never defined
{% if variable is empty %}   // $variable is defined but empty (null, empty string, 0)
```

you may also use the [`default`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html) filter:

```
{% variable|default('') %}
```